# Overlaying map shaper geometries

Tags: coordinate-system, mapshaper

I seem to be getting an issue when trying to create TopoJSON from two shapefiles and then overlaying them with D3. One is a linestring object, a pipe, and then other is the map.

If I upload a zip file with the shapefiles in to mapshaper.org then it does look correct.

I'm actually trying to convert the following GDAL command

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs WGS84 -f GeoJSON output.json input.shp
```

There seems to be on offset, this is the mapshaper command I'm using

```
mapshaper input.shp -proj wgs84 -rename-layers geometries -o output.json bbox no-quantization precision=0.00000000000001 format=topojson
```

When I compare the JSON in the pipe shapefile the coordinates are different so I assume it's not projecting correctly.

D3 working
[image: D3 Working]
D3 not working
[image: D3 not working]
Mapshaper.org working
[image: mapshaper working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from a shapefile already projected to EPSG:27700 into TopoJSON using WGS84 projection I found the solution was to use `init=` as described [here](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-proj) my example became the following.

```
mapshaper map.shp -filter 'DescGroup="Building"' -proj init="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs" wgs84 -rename-layers geometries -o topjson.json bbox no-quantization precision=0.00000000000001 format=topojson
```

Proj4 found here

https://epsg.io/27700-1314.proj4js